# How to authenticate to Bitbucket with atlassian-python-api?

Tags: python, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

I'm using the module https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api to work on Bitbucket server with python.
In their doc, they show a simple way to authenticate:

```
from atlassian import Bitbucket
bitbucket = Bitbucket(
    url='http://localhost:7990',
    username='admin',
    password='admin')
data = bitbucket.project_list()
print(data)
```

However, I'm not getting what url I should specify. Can you please help me with a practical example?
Also, on this doc https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/index.html there are listed alternative ways to authenticate, if you know any more recommended method please let me know.

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate to Bitbucket Server/Data Center (you would host this on your own servers), or to Bitbucket Cloud (https://bitbucket.org)? The example you've included indicates a self-hosted instance of Bitbucket Server/DC. The answer to your question depends on which you're using. Notice in the page you linked, further down is a different example for Bitbucket Cloud auth using OAuth2 (look for `from atlassian.bitbucket import Cloud`).

Answer (score 0):

Currently you need to use api password and slug in order to login.

slug get from your repository url:

```
https://bitbucket.org/{slug}/workspace/repositories
```

app password you can create here:

```
https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/
```

Then login like this:

```
from atlassian.bitbucket import Cloud

cloud = Cloud(url="https://api.bitbucket.org/", username=slug, password=app_password)
```

Comment: @Samuel Liew .This is right place for this answer, the preview one was misplaced. Don't delete proper solution if there any or you can't provide better one.